# Обрезать текст после определенного слова)?

Tags: jquery

Здраствуйте, как обрезать текст после слов Автоэлектрика на Acura. Т.е "на Acura"? Но только в теге img?

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="/uploads/mini/Автоэлектрика на Acura.png" title="Детали ходовой на Acura">
```

Comment: в теге img, в атрибуте src?

Comment: Да все верно в src

Comment: я не до конца понимаю суть, можете привести пример тега

Comment: Внес изменение в вопрос

Comment: о так на много понятней

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var pattern = /\sна\s[A-zА-яёЁ\-]+/;    

$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(pattern, ''));
});
```

Comment: Но как оставить .png, но сделать после Автоэлектрика

Comment: Понял. Да сделал. Но еще один вопрос, у меня на странице например Детали двигателя на Acura. Как оставить Детали двигателя. И т..д

Comment: `$('img').each(...`

Comment: Последнее. на Acura. Это не всегда известно. Т.е нужно не конкретно на Acura. А все что после слов Автоэлектрика (например). Остальное удалять

Comment: @Never3D Отвечающий должен был это угадать? Приведите достаточное количество примеров, исчерпывающих случаи, в которых будет исполняться код.

Comment: Автоэлектрика на Audi
Детали двигателя на Audi
Детали кузова на Audi
Детали кузова на Lada. Мне не нужны слова на и марка машины, единственное, что повторяется это "на"

Comment: Все отлиично, но остается большой пробел Детали двигателя  .png. И вот тут проблема Детали%20двигателя%20Rover.png Rover остается

Comment: `var pattern = /[\s]+на[\s]+[A-zА-яёЁ\-]+/;`

Comment: а как убрать Детали двигателя Rover.png. Rover

Comment: я вам дал абстрактное понятие как сделать а дальше вы сами, суть заключается в том что эта строка не подходит под шаблон и надо еще раз пройтись  по изображения но с другим шаблоном. для этого существую регулярные выражения, благо в интернете миллионы статей, уроков, документаций на различных языках. вот отсюда начинайте изучать https://learn.javascript.ru/regular-expressions-javascript я не смогу прописать за вас все паттерны